# Retrieve last id from Firebird db table

Tags: c#, .net, firebird

retreiving last inserted id

I want to retreive last inserted id from firebird database. Data is succ. inserted, trigger inserts id as it should using generator.

I'm advised to use this syntax

```
 var sql = "INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...  " +
           "RETURNING Id";
```

where `RETURNING` Id should return table Id.

I dont know how to store into variable.

```
int lastId = ...
```

Comment: where you will use the var sql? How do you access your databace?

Comment: I'm accessing db and using this sql as text injected into dapper query but that't not the issue here. Just retrieving last inserted id from database and storing that value into variable.

Comment: I have understood what is your problem. However I should know the way you will execute your query, in order to see how you can getthe id you want. Unfortunately, I have never used the dapper, you refer. Although, I haven't used it, I suppose that the method, which will execute your query, will return a result. For instance if you run a select * from table, you will get the results and subsequently you will read them with. I was thinking an answer like Rada gave you a few seconds before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using scope identity in firebird](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267938/using-scope-identity-in-firebird)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var con = OpenFB2Connection();
var trans = con.BeginTransaction();

var command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...  RETURNING Id");

cmd.Parameters.Add("Id", OleDbType.Integer).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


var Id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //Here is your Id
```

Comment: Depending on your use cases, I found that ExecuteScalar() was giving me the correct result.  Otherwise, in my case ExecuteNonQuery() was returning 1 always.